# Add several GET parameters to urls

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I'm trying to use several GET parameters in a URL.

For example `logout-user` and `clear-cart` - is it possible to do something like:

```
/?clear-cart&&logout-user
```

What would be the correct way to do it? 
I'm using WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want values for them, you just need one ampersand:

```
/?clear-cart&logout-user
```

If you want values, they get equals signs:

```
/?clear-cart=1&logout-user=true
```

Don't forget (if you are outputting these URLs) to pass their values through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) so they don't break your URLs.

Comment: Thank you :) one moment after i post i got to same conclusion and figure it out. Your answer is correct.